# How to set spinnerMode in codebehind

Tags: android, spinner

I could not find a way to set spinnerMode in codebehind. Spinner sets it's spinnerMode property automatically as dialog by default theme. How do I set it while I'm creating a new spinner on code behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the [Android Spinner docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#Spinner%28android.content.Context,%20int%29)

Answer (score 3):

in android >= 3.0 (API 11) you can use this :

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this,null,android.R.style.Widget_Spinner,Spinner.MODE_DROPDOWN);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this.Context, SpinnerMode.Dialog);
```